# how to write the single query in the aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

i am trying this aggregation but how to write single query in this aggregations how to solve the questions. please suggest me .please suggest me two documents switchID are same . but STATUS different one STATUS IS :LIGHTS OFF another STATUS IS:LIGHTS ON . any possible add the query LIGHTS OFF avgduration - LIGHTS ON avgduration

```
db.lights.aggregate({
        $match: {
            CREATE_DATE: {
                $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
                $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")
            }
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            offduration: {
                $divide: [{
                    $subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]
                }, 3600000]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            _id: {
                SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",
                STATUS: "$STATUS"
            },
            avgduration: {
                $avg: "$offduration"
            },
            SWITCHID: {
                $first: "$SWITCHID"
            },
            CREATE_DATE: {
                $first: "$CREATE_DATE"
            },
            RECEIVEDDATE: {
                $first: "$RECEIVEDDATE"
            },
            STATUS: {
                $first: "$STATUS"
            },
            offduration: {
                $first: "$offduration"
            },
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            SWITCHID: 1,
            CREATE_DATE: 1,
            RECEIVEDDATE: 1,
            STATUS: 1,
            avgduration: '$avgduration',
            offduration: '$offduration'
        }
    })
    dblights.aggregate({"$group" : {    
    ...     _id: {
    ...         SWITCHID: "$_id.SWITCHID"
    ...     },
    ...     on_minus_off: { $sum:{ "$cond": [
    ...         { "$eq": [ "$_id.STATUS", "on" ] },
    ...         "$avgduration",
    ...         { $subtract: [ 0, "$avgduration" ] }
    ...     ]}}
    ... }}
    ... ])
```